# Function to sorting recursively a multidimensional array in php by key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of categories and I would like to create a function to sort them by passing a parameter, which the function uses to sort the array.

the array I have is like this:

```php
Array
(
    [1] = Array
        (
            [id] = 1
            [name] = categoryName1
            [parent] = 0
            [sorting] = 1
            [0] = Array
                (
                    [id] = 6
                    [name] = categoryName6
                    [parent] = 1
                    [sorting] = 3
                )

            [1] = Array
                (
                    [id] = 4
                    [name] = categoryName4
                    [parent] = 1
                    [sorting] = 2
                )

            [2] = Array
                (
                    [id] = 3
                    [name] = categoryName3
                    [parent] = 1
                    [sorting] = 1
                    [0] = Array
                        (
                            [id] = 5
                            [name] = categoryName5
                            [parent] = 3
                            [sorting] = 1

                        )

                )

        )

    [2] = Array
        (
            [id] = 2
            [name] = categoryName2
            [parent] = 0
            [sorting] = 2
        )

)
```

I tried with array_multisort like this:

```php
    function recursive_sort(&$array, $sort_key) {
        foreach ( $array as $k => &$v ) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                recursive_sort( $v, $sort_key );
            }
        }
        return array_multisort(array_column($array,$sort_key), SORT_ASC, $array);
    }

    recursive_sort($sorted_categories, 'sorting');
```

but I am getting this error:

array_multisort(): Array sizes are inconsistent

I expect the output:

```php
Array
(
    [1] = Array
        (
            [id] = 1
            [name] = categoryName1
            [parent] = 0
            [sorting] = 1
            [0] = Array
                (
                    [id] = 3
                    [name] = categoryName3
                    [parent] = 1
                    [sorting] = 1
                    [0] = Array
                        (
                            [id] = 5
                            [name] = categoryName5
                            [parent] = 3
                            [sorting] = 1

                        )

                )

            [1] = Array
                (
                    [id] = 4
                    [name] = categoryName4
                    [parent] = 1
                    [sorting] = 2
                )

            [2] = Array
                (
                    [id] = 6
                    [name] = categoryName6
                    [parent] = 1
                    [sorting] = 3
                )

        )

    [2] = Array
        (
            [id] = 2
            [name] = categoryName2
            [parent] = 0
            [sorting] = 2
        )

)
```

with this function:

```php
recursive_sort($sorted_categories, 'sorting');
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood why i can't sort the array properly ... the child categories must be agglomerated inside a key (such as "child") like this:

```
Array
(
[1] = Array
    (
        [id] = 1
        [name] = categoryName1
        [parent] = 0
        [sorting] = 1
        [child] = Array
            (
                [0] = Array
                    (
                        [id] = 6
                        [name] = categoryName6
                        [parent] = 1
                        [sorting] = 3
                    )

                [1] = Array
                    (
                        [id] = 4
                        [name] = categoryName4
                        [parent] = 1
                        [sorting] = 2
                    )

                [2] = Array
                    (
                        [id] = 3
                        [name] = categoryName3
                        [parent] = 1
                        [sorting] = 1
                        [child] = Array
                            (
                                [0] = Array
                                    (
                                        [id] = 5
                                        [name] = categoryName5
                                        [parent] = 3
                                        [sorting] = 1
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )

[2] = Array
    (
        [id] = 2
        [name] = categoryName2
        [parent] = 0
        [sorting] = 2
    )
```

)

so i can sort the array with this function

```
function recursive_sort(&$array, $sort_key) {

    foreach ( $array as $k => &$v ) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            recursive_sort( $v, $sort_key );
        }
    }

    // at least 2 elements
    if ($array[1]) {
        return array_multisort( array_column( $array, $sort_key ), SORT_DESC, $array );
    }
}
recursive_sort($sorted_categories, 'id');
```